# Integrate user accounts commerce server into wordpress

Tags: wordpress, e-commerce, blogs, microsoft-commerce-server, commerce

For the moment I have the following construction for my e-commerce platform:

- Kentico CMS
- Microsoft commerce server

I'm looking to integrate a blog in this concstruction. Altough Kentico CMS has blogging possibilities. Wordpress would fit better with our goals.

However I want to know if there are any possibilites with using the user account defined in commerce server in wordpress for commenting? Users registered on the webshop should be able to comment on a post using the user account registered on the webshop.

Thank you for your effort!

Comment: Maybe using: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/openid/ ?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: **NO**

The long answer:

No, you cannot.

Two systems use entirely different table sturctures for keeping user info (ID, Username, password, etc). You would need to heavily modify wordpress or kentico in order to sync table structures (which is pointless).

Only possible alternatives I see are:

Write a Migration script which will migrate all the necessary data from kentico DB to WPDB.

Write an iterative script which will create users for Wordpress based on their username and e-mail. That way you can send them their passwords.

---

Extremely simple (but effective) way would be to make comments FFA and use Disqus or WP native commenting system with Akismet.